# How to create unit record data from summary table

Tags: r

I have a summary table I need to expand into unit-level observations to run test statistics on.

The summary table looks like this

```
tbl_summmary <-
  tibble(
    outcome = c("A (%)", "B (%)", "C (%)", "D (%)", "Total (n)"),
    group_1 = c(.25, .25, .125, .325, 10),
    group_2 = c(.50, 0.0, .325, .125, 20),
    group_3 = c(.10, .40, .125, .325, 40))

tbl_summmary
```

[image]

The result needs to be a long format dataframe of the data described in the summary table.

```
df_simulation <- 
  bind_rows(
    tibble(
      group = 1,
      outcome = c(
        rep("A", .25*10), 
        rep("B", .25*10), 
        rep("C", .125*10), 
        rep("D", .325*10))),
    tibble(
      group = 2,
      outcome = c(
        rep("A", .50*20), 
        rep("B", .00*20), 
        rep("C", .325*20), 
        rep("D", .125*20))),
    tibble(
      group = 3,
      outcome = c(
        rep("A", .10*40), 
        rep("B", .40*40), 
        rep("C", .125*40), 
        rep("D", .325*40))))

df_simulation
```

[image]

However, the code needs to iterate over multiple variables and multiple groups. Typing out each group and variable manually like in the above won't be scalable. A way of doing this programmatically would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `tidyr::uncount` after some additional data wrangling steps:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# Get df of totals
totals <- tbl_summmary[nrow(tbl_summmary),] |> 
  pivot_longer(-outcome, names_to = "group", names_prefix = "group_") |> 
  select(group, total = value)
# Get df of outcomes
outcomes <- tbl_summmary[-nrow(tbl_summmary),] |> 
  mutate(outcome = gsub("^(\\w+).*$", "\\1", outcome)) |> 
  pivot_longer(-outcome, names_to = "group", names_prefix = "group_") |> 
  left_join(totals, by = "group") |> 
  # We need integers, so use round
  mutate(n = round(value * total)) |>
  select(group, outcome, n) |> 
  uncount(n) |> 
  mutate(group = as.numeric(group)) |> 
  arrange(group, outcome)

count(outcomes, outcome, group)
#> # A tibble: 11 × 3
#>    outcome group     n
#>    <chr>   <dbl> <int>
#>  1 A           1     2
#>  2 A           2    10
#>  3 A           3     4
#>  4 B           1     2
#>  5 B           3    16
#>  6 C           1     1
#>  7 C           2     6
#>  8 C           3     5
#>  9 D           1     3
#> 10 D           2     2
#> 11 D           3    13

identical(df_simulation, outcomes)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

I do like the approach by @stefan.

If you want the format you requested, it can be done by listing the outcome values by the total amount then unnesting the values, then putting it into long format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df <- tbl_summmary |> 
      mutate(across(starts_with("group"), ~ .x *.x[5])) |> 
      rowwise() |> 
      mutate(across(starts_with("group"), ~ 
                      ifelse(.x != 0,
                             list(rep(str_remove(outcome, " \\(%\\)"), .x)),
                             list(NA_character_))))
df[-5, -1] |> 
  unnest_wider(col = everything(), names_sep = "_") |> 
  stack() |> 
  mutate(ind = str_extract(str_remove(ind, "_\\d+$"), "\\d"), .before = 1) |> 
  rename(group = ind, outcome = values) |> 
  drop_na()

   outcome group
1        A     1
2        B     1
3        C     1
4        D     1
5        A     1
6        B     1
7        D     1
8        D     1
9        A     2
10       C     2
11       D     2
12       A     2
13       C     2
14       D     2
15       A     2
16       C     2
17       A     2
18       C     2
19       A     2
20       C     2
21       A     2
22       C     2
23       A     2
24       A     2
25       A     2
26       A     2
27       A     3
28       B     3
29       C     3
30       D     3
31       A     3
32       B     3
33       C     3
34       D     3
35       A     3
36       B     3
37       C     3
38       D     3
39       A     3
40       B     3
41       C     3
42       D     3
43       B     3
44       C     3
45       D     3
46       B     3
47       D     3
48       B     3
49       D     3
50       B     3
51       D     3
52       B     3
53       D     3
54       B     3
55       D     3
56       B     3
57       D     3
58       B     3
59       D     3
60       B     3
61       D     3
62       B     3
63       B     3
64       B     3
```